# Order of evaluation of Hamcrest CombinableMatcher

Tags: java, mockito, hamcrest

I wanted to write a logic for matcher like `matcher_1 AND matcher_2 OR matcher_3 and matcher_4` where `matcher_i` are just placeholder for hamcrest matchers.

I decided to write it using `CombinableMatcher` like this -

`new CombinableMatcher<String>(matcher_1).and(matcher_2).or(matcher_3).and(matcher_4)`

Now, the question is in which order matchers will be evaluated ?

Will it  be `((((matcher_1) AND matcher_2) OR matcher_3) and matcher_4)` or
any other order like `((matcher_1 AND matcher_2) OR (matcher_3 and matcher_4))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matcher results will be evaluated from left to right. So, it will be `((((matcher_1) AND matcher_2) OR matcher_3) and matcher_4)` and not `((matcher_1 AND matcher_2) OR (matcher_3 and matcher_4))`.

Following example ran in mockito 3.11 and hamcrest 2.2 proves the above -

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public class SomeTest {
    
        @Mock
        SomeInterface mock;
    
    
        @Test
        public void test(){
    
            when(mock.complicatedMethod(eq(1), MockitoHamcrest.argThat(
    
                    new CombinableMatcher<String>(equalTo("hello"))
                            .and(containsString("ello"))
                            .or(CoreMatchers.<String>instanceOf(String.class))
                            .and(containsString("XYZ"))
    
    
            ) )).thenReturn("done");
    
            System.out.println(mock.complicatedMethod(1 ,"hello"));// Prints null
    
        }
    
    
    
    }

interface SomeInterface {

    public String complicatedMethod(int i , String str) ;
}
```

If matcher results which were evaluated in this order `((matcher_1 AND matcher_2) OR (matcher_3 and matcher_4))` [Which is by the way Java precedence order for boolean operator], then "done" would have been printed but it fails and null is printed which means `((((matcher_1) AND matcher_2) OR matcher_3) and matcher_4)` is what it is considering.

Answer (score 0):

Good to see that someone understands the idea of composing matchers.

I'm wondering why you're concerned with the ordering of matchers? Ideally it shouldn't matter, since you also don't know how often a matcher will be called.

If you have issues at this level of detail, it might be best to write a custom matcher.